# Install WebView2 Winforms

Tags: windows, winforms, windows-installer, webview2

I have a winforms application, it's using WebView2, when I build in release the app works fine, when I attempt to use Windows installer project to create a setup exe file for the project, the files get copied but it always throws an error, the most recent one was that edge can't read or write to its directory.
Does anyone know if there is something I am missing please ?

I tried windows installer, advanced installer and winrar SFX

Comment: [WebView2 Deployment Visual Studio installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/samples/wv2deploymentvsinstallersample) -- [WiX Custom Action to deploy the WebView2 Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/samples/wv2deploymentwixcustomactionsample)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using the default user data folder which will be a subfolder of the folder containing the host app executable file. When installed in Program Files your process won't have write access to this folder. You need to specify a different user data folder. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/user-data-folder?tabs=win32#the-default-udf-location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @David Risney, the problem was the installation directory, once I moved the installation to a directory the user had write access to the problem was solved.